# Converting Firebase object(s) to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a working code to read the data from the Firebase. Now I would like to convert the objects in arrays.
I found a lot, but unfortunately nothing works for me. I hope someone has an idea and can help me. I would be very grateful for any help.

```
  firebase.database().ref("/Verrechnung/Messner").orderByChild("Time").on('value', function(snapshot){
  let elm = document.getElementById("data");
  elm.innerHTML = '';

  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    elm.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(childData.Time)
    + JSON.stringify(childData.Kennzeichen)
    + JSON.stringify(childData.Adresse) 
    + JSON.stringify(childData.Provision);
  })
})
    getData();
```

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5VjN.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLJKM.jpg)

```
 "Verrechnung" : {
        "Messner" : {
          "-Lq5fgQFGiM1OPr-vQPP" : {
            "Adresse" : "Teschnergasse 31, 1180 Wien, Österreich",
            "Kennzeichen" : "W-7637TX",
            "Provision" : "€ 1,50",
            "Time" : "20191001113751"
          },
          "-Lq6389RYSY9LPOsjr7a" : {
            "Adresse" : "Eisteichstraße, 1110 Wien, Österreich",
            "Kennzeichen" : "W-7637TX",
            "Provision" : "€ 1,50",
            "Time" : "20191001132440"
          },
          "-LqAAhgUWJs_8_AQvqX1" : {
            "Adresse" : "Gentzgasse 123, 1180 Wien, Österreich",
            "Kennzeichen" : "W-7637TX",
            "Provision" : "€ 1,50",
            "Time" : "20191002083619"
          },
          "-LqAwfg5WSYeBG8yGoIV" : {
            "Adresse" : "Raffelspergergasse, 1190 Wien, Österreich",
            "Kennzeichen" : "W-7637TX",
            "Provision" : "€ 1,50",
            "Time" : "20191002121014"
          },
          "-LqFtZJBS_-LCbsENi2a" : {
            "Adresse" : "Landwehrstraße 6, 1110 Wien, Österreich",
            "Kennzeichen" : "W-7637TX",
            "Provision" : "€ 1,50",
            "Time" : "20191003111445"
          },
        },
```

Comment: You need to provide additional detail in order to get an answer here -- for example, what does the data in your database look like, and how does that translate to what you would like an array of.

Comment: @robsiemb thanks, i edit the post. I would like to convert the objects into arrays so that I can process them further.

Comment: If you simply want to create an array from object have you tried `Object.values(data)`? Do you want to mutate each element shape? As @robsiemb points out, what is your input and expected output?

Comment: @davidschober That looks like its probably the output you currently are getting, not the output you want.

Notably, you're not currently building an array, you're just appending to a string.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. I've already seen that go with console.log(array). So that I do not create a string. But that did not work.

Comment: @DrewReese no I have not. I'll try it right away.

Comment: @DrewReese i change the innerHTML to console.log(Object.values(data));
But that did not work :/

Comment: @DavidSchober My apologies but I guess I should have specified that in `Object.values(data)` that "data" would be whatever variable you have that is the object you want to turn into an array. Objects are associative arrays of key-value pairs, so `Object.values` returns an array of the values.

Comment: @DrewReese I was sorry too. I had it misunderstood. I've tried it now with "Time", but unfortunately also with no result :/

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you. I edit the post. Hope it helps. I have cut the code a little bit, but it repeats the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers in the comment thread.

This seems to do roughly the right thing for me:

```
let elm = document.getElementById("data");

firebase.database().ref("/Verrechnung/Messner").orderByChild("original").on('value', (snapshot) => {
  let dataArray = {};
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    dataArray[childSnapshot.key] = childSnapshot.val();
    console.log(childSnapshot.key);
  });
  elm.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
});
```

This doesn't give exactly the output you are looking for -- it only gives the innermost array.  If you want to wrap this in dictionaries based on the collection name (as in your example) it would look slightly different.

Obviously I'm just injecting the array as JSON back into the document, you should do whatever is the correct thing that you need.

Likewise, its totally ok to declare dataArray outside of the callback too if you need access to it.

You might be able to use `once` instead of `on`.  See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data).  Alternatively, if you do want this to be constantly updated, using 'value' may not be the most efficient listen mode.

Comment: Sorry for the large number of edits, this should be the correct version.

Comment: Thanks man. I put the "let elm = document.getElementById("data");" over "let dataArray" and now it works. Not nicely structured, just in a row. But for my purposes it does not have to look nice. 1000 Thanks from me!